# unhashable type error when trying to convert an rna string

Tags: python

In the code I'm currently working on, I have a dictionary called codon_dict, which has a list of all the three letter codons that translate to their respective amino acids. I also have a table called rnaCodonTable, with its values being the single letter amino acid and keys being the three letter codon to which it corresponds.  What I'm trying to do is get an rna base string that takes every three base pairs, recognize it as a codon from my dictionary, and translate it to the single letter amino acids they code for. This is my set up so far:

```
for i in range (0, len(self.codon_dict), 3): 
            codon = self.codon_dict[i:i+3] 
            print (codon)
            if codon in NucParams.codon_dict():
                self.codon_dict[codon] +=1

#codons are then converted to amino acids.
            temp_aa = NucParams.rnaCodonTable(codon)
            if temp_aa in self.aa_dict:
                self.aa_dict[temp_aa] += 1
```

I've been getting this error message: codon = self.codon_dict[i:i+3] 
TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'

I'm not sure what I had done wrong here. could someone explain to me the error?

Here is how rnaCodonTable looks like:

```
 rnaCodonTable = {
    # RNA codon table
    # U
    'UUU': 'F', 'UCU': 'S', 'UAU': 'Y', 'UGU': 'C', # UxU
    'UUC': 'F', 'UCC': 'S', 'UAC': 'Y', 'UGC': 'C', # UxC
    'UUA': 'L', 'UCA': 'S', 'UAA': '-', 'UGA': '-', # UxA
    'UUG': 'L', 'UCG': 'S', 'UAG': '-', 'UGG': 'W', # UxG
    # C
    'CUU': 'L', 'CCU': 'P', 'CAU': 'H', 'CGU': 'R', # CxU
    'CUC': 'L', 'CCC': 'P', 'CAC': 'H', 'CGC': 'R', # CxC
    'CUA': 'L', 'CCA': 'P', 'CAA': 'Q', 'CGA': 'R', # CxA
    'CUG': 'L', 'CCG': 'P', 'CAG': 'Q', 'CGG': 'R', # CxG
    # A
    'AUU': 'I', 'ACU': 'T', 'AAU': 'N', 'AGU': 'S', # AxU
    'AUC': 'I', 'ACC': 'T', 'AAC': 'N', 'AGC': 'S', # AxC
    'AUA': 'I', 'ACA': 'T', 'AAA': 'K', 'AGA': 'R', # AxA
    'AUG': 'M', 'ACG': 'T', 'AAG': 'K', 'AGG': 'R', # AxG
    # G
    'GUU': 'V', 'GCU': 'A', 'GAU': 'D', 'GGU': 'G', # GxU
    'GUC': 'V', 'GCC': 'A', 'GAC': 'D', 'GGC': 'G', # GxC
    'GUA': 'V', 'GCA': 'A', 'GAA': 'E', 'GGA': 'G', # GxA
    'GUG': 'V', 'GCG': 'A', 'GAG': 'E', 'GGG': 'G' # GxG
    }
```

Comment: Can you post what `self.codon_dict` contains?

Comment: codon_dict = {}
            for aa in self.rnaCodonTable.keys():
                codon_dict[aa] = 0
            self.codon_dict = codon_dict

Comment: and the keys in rnaCodonTable are the three letter codons

Comment: What is the point of the `codon_dict` if all it does it contain the same keys as `rnaCodonTable`?

Comment: I wanted to create codon_dict so tat later, when I want to find the codon composition of the string, I'd just have to return codon_dict.

Comment: The problem is that he's creating the slice `i:i+3` then trying to get that key from the `self.codon_dict` dictionary. Obviously `i:i+3` isn't actually a key in the dictionary, which would return `KeyError` (which would be obvious) if it wasn't for the fact that `slice` objects aren't hashable so Python KNOWS it can't search for that

Comment: I'm not really sure what he's trying to do, but it looks like there's a variable missing there, as BurhanKhalid suggests in his answer. I think he's trying look up a slice from the string (e.g. `self.codon_dict[some_string[i:i+3]]`) and simply forgot to put that in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> could someone explain to me the error?

Dictionaries are a key lookup table and the keys have to be hashable. In your code, the value of `i:i:3` is of an unhashable type *slice* which cannot be a key of a dictionary.

Here is a simplified version of your error, using another unhashable type, a list:

```
>>> d = {}  # An empty dictionary
>>> d[[1,2]] = 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

---

I think I understand what you are trying to do, I believe you have a string that represents an RNA chain, like this:

```
s = 'AUUGCUAAAAAGGAGGAUUUUCG'
```

You would like to get the corresponding codons from the `rnaCodonTable` dictionary.

So, the problem is to split the RNA chain into three letter bits, which you can then lookup in the codon table:

To make life easier, use the [`grouper` recipe](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes):

```
from itertools import izip_longest

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)

s = 'AUUGCUAAAAAGGAGGAUUUUCG'

codons = []

for pair in grouper(s, 3):
    codons.append(rna_codon_table[''.join(pair)])

print('Codons: {}'.format(''.join(codons))
```

`grouper` will return a tuple, and our keys are strings so we join the tuple with a blank string to create a three-letter pairing:

```
>>> for pair in grouper(s, 3):
...    print(pair)
...
('A', 'U', 'U')
('G', 'C', 'U')
('A', 'A', 'A')
('A', 'A', 'A')
('G', 'G', 'A')
('G', 'G', 'U')
('U', 'U', 'U')
('U', 'C', 'G')
>>> for pair in grouper(s,3):
...     print(''.join(pair))
...
AUU
GCU
AAA
AAA
GGA
GGU
UUU
UCG
```

Next, we fetch the codons corresponding to each three letter pair and store them in a list. Finally, we print the list out as a string.

You can combine the loop into a generator and then consume it directly, like this:

```
codons = ''.join(rna_codon_table[''.join(pair)] for pair in grouper(s, 3))
```

I changed the case of your dictionary as per the [Python style guide](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions).

Comment: oh, so making my list in to a tuple should do the trick? I'm not using a list, though. I have a string...

Comment: @user3504701 actually you're using a `slice`, as evidenced by your traceback

Comment: thanks. I've also heard that you could possibly make a dictionary hashable with frozenset. is it possible I could use that as well?

Comment: @user3504701 no, because you're missing something basic. There's literally not a string in the code you posted above. Read my comments on your question, and re-read the answer that BurhanKhalid gave you. You're not using a string here, but you're insistent that you are, so this error seems typographical.